# Access ELF string table section header

Tags: c, elf

Assume the following:

```
Elf_Section_Header *sectionHeaderTable //points to the start of a ELF section header table
Elf_Section_Header *symtabHeader  //points to the start of the symtab section header
```

Why doesn't the following point me to the associated string table section header?

```
Elf_Section_Header *strTabSectionHeader = (Elf_Section_Header *)((char *)sectionHeaderTable + (symtabHeader->strtab_index));
```

`strTabSectionHeader->type == SHT_STRTAB` is equal to false

How should I point to the associated string table section header?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably the `->strtab_index` struct member is referring to the `sh_name` member of the symbol table header (as named in the ELF spec).

This is actually an index *within* the section header string table section, not the location of a string table.

String tables are stored in their own sections.  The section header string table in particular is located by the `e_shstrndx` member of the ELF header.  This is an index into the section header table - thus `sectionHeaderTable[elf_header->e_shstrndx]` is likely what you want (the section header for the section header string table).

Answer (score 0):

Each Binary generally contains three String tables -

```
1. .dynstr
2. .shstrtab
3. .strtab
```

IN the above question we are concerned with .shstrtab which when expanded stands for - Section Header STRing TABle. Upon reading the ELF header we find the following field in ELF header - e_shstrndx. This is the index where we can find .shstrtab. Following formula can be used to calculate how it will be done -

```
offset = ((elfHdr.e_shstrndx)*elfHdr.e_shentsize)+elfHdr.e_shoff
```

Meaning of each parameter -

```
elfHdr.e_shstrndx = index where we can find .shstrtab
elfHdr.e_shentsize = Size of each Section Header
elfHdr.e_shoff = Offset at which section header starts.
```

PLease comment if u need more details

Answer (score 0):

A section header’s sh_name member holds an index into the section header string table section, as designated by the e_shstrndx member of the ELF header.
[ELF Specification](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf)